# Is there any place I can find all the hex code color values for VSCode's "Default High Contrast" theme?

Tags: colors, themes, visual-studio-code

I really like VSCode's "Default High Contrast" theme. It reminds me of old vector arcade cabinets, like [Tempest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(video_game)). I'd like to know what some of the colors are for elements such as the font colors, the scrollbar colors, the "column guide" line, the background color on highlight, the border-box-color on the line where the cursor sits, etc.

I have explored the various `ctrl+shift+p` commands to see if any sort of "list colors" commands exist, and as far as I can tell they do not.

I have explored the [themeing](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) documentation to see if there's any way to "read" what the current colors are. There does not appear to be any way to "read" values from an existent theme, only write to an existent theme. Or, you can write a theme from scratch.

I have googled a fair bit but not found information on the colors used in this theme anywhere.

If this information isn't readily available online or in the application (or the application files) I suppose I will explore taking screenshots and extracting the colors directly from the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your color theme to the default high constrast theme. Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings`. This will generate a file with all of the colors currently applied to your editor.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j6addd1Z was the output from that if anybody is curious